# loop gives me error. If i have error i wana go for next cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, error-handling

i have this code. I need a help. When in pivot tabel3 vba couldnt find this: Sheets("EXO").Range("N" & y).Value i wana go for next cell until vba do not find this this Sheets("EXO").Range("N" & y).Value and after then vba should do copy and paste part of loop Could u please help me ?

```
Sub FILL_vALUES_EXO()
i = 1
y = 9
rng = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("EXO").Range("N9:N67"))


Do While i < rng
    
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Sheets("EXO").Range("N" & y).copy
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("RootCause").ClearAllFilters
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("RootCause").CurrentPage = _
       Sheets("EXO").Range("N" & y).Value
      

    
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.copy
    Range("O" & y).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

   Range("O4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.copy
    Range("O" & y & ":R" & y).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
y = y + 1
i = i + 1
```

end sub

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub FILL_vALUES_EXO()
Dim shtEXO As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, y As Integer, Rng As Integer

i = 1
y = 9
Rng = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("EXO").Range("N9:N67"))


Do While i < Rng
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Set shtEXO = Worksheets("EXO")
    
    'removed this unnecessary copy operation
    'shtEXO.Range("N" & y).Copy
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("RootCause")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .CurrentPage.Name = shtEXO.Range("N" & y).Value
    End With
    
    Range("B6").End(xlDown).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy
    Range("O" & y).Paste

    Range("O4").Copy
    Range("O" & y & ":R" & y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _ 
Operation:=xlNone, _ 
SkipBlanks:=False, _ 
Transpose:=False
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    y = y + 1
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

You may ask questions if something confuses you.

Edit:

As per OP, he/she wants to add error handling

```
...
On Error Goto JumpToNext 'if error is encountered, jump to whatever label you choose (JumpToNext)
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("RootCause")
   .ClearAllFilters
   .CurrentPage.Name = shtEXO.Range("N" & y).Value
End With
...
'other codes
...
JumpToNext:  'error handler will jump here if it encounters an error, skipping the codes in between
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    y = y + 1
    i = i + 1
Loop
On Error GoTo 0 'disable error handler so that next procedures will execute normally
```

Comment: the same problem. VBA Show me eror whem he couldnt find cell (N y) value in filter rootcause and i wana if vba couldnt find cell value in filed rootcause i wana skip copy and paste part of this loop and i wana vba to check next cell in this loop.

Comment: i thougth about to use u know if error or on error resume next but they didnt worked, so may be u have another option to solve this ?

Comment: what error do you see? do you have screenshot of the errors and sample data of what you want to process?

Comment: Error that vba couldnt find this  .CurrentPage.Name = shtEXO.Range("N" & y).Value and i wana to skip this if i will get this error.

Comment: Still i see error instead of doing next step.